# Is $\textrm{d}x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, infinitesimals

Is an infinitesimal a real number? Can ["abuse of Leibniz's notation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Derivative) be justified by claiming that an infinitesimal is a real number? If not, what is an infinitesimal?

Comment: what is $\mbox{d}x/2$? Does it satisfy $0<\mbox{d}x/2<\mbox{d}x$?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number).

Comment: @DanielRust How is $\textrm{d}x$ defined? $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} x = \textrm{d}x$? Vincenzo's link (I think) tells me straightforwardly that your inequality would be satisfied, because the hyperreals obey simple order laws of the reals?

Comment: @DanielRust Actually, using hyperreals means you're doing non-standard analysis...

Comment: For dx as an infinitesimal, it depends on whether the property described is a first-order property, so we can apply the "transfer principle" and elementary equivalence, i.e., the Hyperreals are elementary equivalent to the standard Reals.

Comment: @user89 You're the one talking about $dx$, so it is up to do you define what it means. On the other hand, $\lim_{x\to 0} x=0$ is a real number.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That's true, but I don't even know how I should define them. You pointed out the mistake in my first attempt. "In spirit" I am thinking of the $\textrm{d}x$ in $\frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}t}$, for instance.

Comment: It's not (if it did, it'd have a decimal expansion), but you _can_ come up with other sets—like the hyperreals–that do have it. However, when calculus was made rigorous, they didn't choose to do it that way; instead, they made arguments based entirely on real numbers (now known as "epsilon-delta proofs").

Comment: Oh yeah dude @user89 I think the question I told you about in your last question included that.

Comment: @columbus8myhw So why do we still love standard real analysis? Why haven't we moved onto non-standard analysis?

Comment: @user89: I think in part because too many books have been written using standard analysis and too many people have been trained in standard analysis. It would be too hard to throw all those books aside and teach all those people the non-standard approach. Same reason helps explain why Windows is the dominating O.S: you cannot just get rid of all the old programs written for windows and it is not practical to retrain everyone to learn a new O.S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An infinitesimal is an element of a non-standard model of the Reals (where the existence of this model is given by Compactness and Lowenheim-Skolem theorems; model of uncountable cardinality) that does not exist
in the standard Reals, because an infinitesimal does not satisfy the Archimedean property/axiom of the standard Reals.

Comment: This is only half correct. There are two main streams of nonstandard analysis. In the first, developed by Abraham Robinson from model-theoretic foundations, infinitesimals show up as new emements of an extension of the real numbers to the *hyperreals*. Infinitesimals are constructed; they are not real numbers. In the second main stream, Edward Nelson's internal set theory, new axioms give us a new ability to distinguish some real numbers from others. We acquire a sort of X-ray vision which allows us to see infinitesimals where before we could see only zero; infinitesimals are real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Infinitesimal quantities are, historically, a less consistent way of thinking of limits. The derivatives and the integrals where useful, but the correct idea of limits wasn't developed until more than hundred years after Newton and Leibniz.

In calculus the idea of limits has replaced the idea of infinitesimals. But of course, $dx$ could be thought of as $\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\Delta x$.

Only when identifying $dx=0$ it is correct that $dx\in\Bbb R$. But one could study the ring of formal polynomials $\Bbb R[dx]$ (or the field of rational functions $\Bbb R(dx)$) in which the constant terms correspond to the real numbers and here $dx\in \Bbb R[dx]$.

Comment: This is a reasonably accurate picture of the history of mathematics up to about 50 years ago. At that point, _non-standard analysis_ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonstandardAnalysis.html) was developed and shown to be just as rigorously correct as standard analysis.

Comment: @DavidK: wouldn't just $\Bbb R[dx]$ constitute a theory of infinitesimals?

Comment: I tried to learn nonstandard analysis just once, about 20 years ago, so I am not an expert, but I don't think it uses $dx$ as a specific infinitesimal value.